# How to change clentId after initialization in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to make Google Analytics generate programmatically a new clientId, but when i remove the tracker and then create a new one, it has the same clientId as the previous one. What i want to achieve is that after some actions on the page GA should begin to treat and track the current user as a new one. What i'm trying right now, not the exact code:

```
ga.remove();
cookies.remove('_ga');
cookies.remove('_gid');
cookies.remove('_gat');
ga.create('UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto')
```

though _gid is changing but not _ga